# Trouble converting equation into as3

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, linear-algebra

I was reading online tutorial about vectors and I was at finding angle between vectors [here](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vch10/vch10_6.html)

Here the author uses below vectors and get the angle 35.26 degrees by replacing the equation.

```
Vector a is (4, 4, 4)T     Vector b is (4, 0, 4)T     Calculate: au · bu  =  cos θ
```

I converted it into as3 and used same vectors to compare the answer

Code:

```
var a:Vector3D = new Vector3D(4, 4, 4);
var b:Vector3D = new Vector3D(4, 0, 4);

//magnitute
var am:Number = Math.sqrt(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y + a.z * a.z);
var bm:Number = Math.sqrt(b.x * b.x + b.y * b.y + b.z * b.z);
trace(am,bm);
//normalized
var aa:Vector3D = new Vector3D(a.x/am,a.y/am,a.z/am);
var bb:Vector3D = new Vector3D(b.x/bm,b.y/bm,a.z/bm);
//dot product
var costheta:Number = aa.x * bb.x + aa.y * bb.y + aa.z * bb.z;

trace(costheta);
//angle in degrees
trace( Math.acos(costheta) * 180 / Math.PI);
```

Output:

I got both radians and degress correctly as given in the tutorial

```
0.816496580927726
35.264389682754654
```

Now, the problem is, I used [another example](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vch10/vch10_7.html) using different vectors and just replaced the variable in my as3 program

```
f  =  (4, 3, 2)T
g  =  (-1, 4, 4)T
```

Expected output (from website)

```
0.51721
58.885
```

I was expecting correct output but its not matching with the authors answer in the web site.

```
0.3879049103011416
67.17580053566918
```

Same case with [another example.](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vch10/vch10_10.html)

```
p  =  ( -2, 4, 3)T
q  =  ( 3, 1, -4)T
```

Expected output

```
-0.50985 
120.654°
```

My output

```
0.2549249642552304
75.23086102240184
```

Where is the mistake? What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
var bb:Vector3D = new Vector3D(b.x/bm,b.y/bm,a.z/bm);
```

You made a typo. It should be

```
var bb:Vector3D = new Vector3D(b.x/bm,b.y/bm,b.z/bm);
```

Comment: Thanks for catching , it was late night 2:30AM :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want things to work without getting hands dirty with math - you can use angleBetween(Vecotr3D,Vecotr3D) method of Vecotr3D class. Heres an example code:

```
var cameraPos:Vector3D=new Vector3D(view.camera.x,view.camera.y,view.camera.z);
var angleInRadians:Number=Vector3D.angleBetween(mesh[i].forwardVector,cameraPos);
```

Comment: what is mesh[i].forwardVector?

Comment: instance of Vector3D class